# How do i put two divs in a column on top of each other in a media query?

Tags: css

So I am in the process of mobilizing my website and I want to be able to change the way my page looks when on an iPhone.

I have two divs, one that floats left, and one that floats right so they are horizontally next to each other.
However, I am trying to figure out how can I change these two "blocks" so that they are on top of each other when looking on a phone? Here is my code for the desktop version:

```
<header class="intro-about">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="left" style="background-color: #282828;">
            <h1 class="text-center">Get to know my work</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="right" style="background-color: #282828;">
            <h1 class="text-center">Get to know me</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And it looks like this:

[image: desktop version]

However, I am trying to get it to look like this on a mobile phone:

[image: mobile version]

I'm looking to use media queries too in my css.

Comment: Look into flexbox, its much easier to create layouts like this! There are heaps of great courses online

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to do using `display:flex` and `@media(max-width)`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /*Do not forget next line, or items won't wrap*/
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  padding: 1rem;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}
.left {
  background-color: blue;
}
.right {
  background-color: grey;
}

/*Layout changes on screen width 700px*/
@media(max-width: 700px) {
  .item { 
    flex: 1 0 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item left">Some left content</div>
  <div class="item right">Some right content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figure out at which width you want to make them stack, then add the following to your CSS with the width after `max-width:`

```
@media {max-width: 700px) {
    .left, .right {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```